# restfb falls back on previous proxy if new proxy fails

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection, restfb

I am trying to get proxy changes to work with restfb. I am changing proxy details in a running JVM. Scenarios covered:

1. No proxy at first, fails as expected, configured proxy, works as expected.
2. **Configured correct proxy, works as expected, changed to incorrect proxy, works this time as well, instead of failing.**
3. Overridden method openConnection(URL url) of class DefaultWebRequestor, then tried step two mentioned above, first call succeeded, second call failed, as expected.

My confusion is:

- How is it working before I override the method openConnection the first time?
- Seeing that it works, why does it fall back on the previously working proxy if newly configured proxy fails?

I could not find any place in restfb source where the proxy settings are being cached. Checked and verified that HttpURLConnection is also not caching settings that way.
The URL being hit is something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=january+10&type=post&limit=10&access_token=myaccesstoken&format=json
```